# How to avoid html tags in html title bar

Tags: html, css

I would like to display dynamic values in html title and i have defined the title in database.
While displaying into the title it's showing the html tags like `<B> ... </B>`

i have defined in database is : `<B>elcuidado del cabello</B>`

i would like to avoid html tags in title.please advise.

please find the below code:

```
<c:forEach items="${blogArtic2}" var="dynImg">
<title>${dynImg.article_title_text}</title>
<meta name="Keywords" content="${dynImg.keyword_text}" />
<meta name="Description" content="${dynImg.article_shot_desc}" />
</c:forEach>

<B>elcuidado del cabello</B>
```

Please suggest me.
Thank in advance.
Vijay

Comment: You shouldn't store the title with deprecated HTML in the database. Your goal should be to fix the values in the db instead of fixing them after retrieving.

Comment: What kind of template engine are you using?

Comment: You also have the title outputting in what looks like a foreach block.

Comment: @Anthony while you are absolutely right, I must protest your use of the word "deprecated". `<b>` was never deprecated, only discouraged, and is not obsolete even today.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast It looks like vijay is using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).

Comment: Don't get the `title` within a `foreach` loop. Also, strip off the `HTML` tags before storing the info into the database. Not on the moment you'll be displaying it.

Comment: @MrLister: I hesitated to use that word, but it's the closest fit compared to "style-based markup that may still be in the current standard is highly discouraged and unnecessary."

Comment: @Broxzier Pretty sure he's not using Smarty. Smarty looks a lot different.

Comment: That's not smarty. At least not a tpl file. My guess is ColdFusion.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast Not _"a lot different"_, but you're right. Smarty's syntax is `{$obj.prop}` instead of `${obj.prop}`. http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl

Comment: @Broxzier also a foreach loop looks like `{foreach from=... item=...}` and not `<c:forEach items=... var=...>`.

Comment: @Anthony I know, but words like that have a very precise meaning, and if you're using them in a different way, you may confuse people. It's confusing enough with all the terminology as it is.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast - deleted that comment... Found it! http://www.sharptiles.org/